# How to deal with arrays in the QuickMap function in Flowgear

Tags: flowgear

I need to match one field called defaultAddress in NetSuite into several fields (Address1, city， State, PostCode and Country) in Autotask.

> IIF(ISEMPTY({defaultAddress}), "No Address is provided",SPLIT(REPLACE({defaultAddress}, "", ","), ","))

I have used several Quickmap functions and I have successfully split the original default address into an array. But I can't use array[index] to get a certain part.

Is there a better way that I can split the address and match it with the corresponding fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickmap is backed by VB script, so the way to use indexing is (0) instead of [0] for C#.
You can use:
`IIF(ISEMPTY({defaultAddress}), "No Address is provided",SPLIT({defaultAddress}, ","))(0)`
`IIF(ISEMPTY({defaultAddress}), "No Address is provided",SPLIT({defaultAddress}, ","))(1)`

You can see a simple example here: https://flowgear.me/s/b4Dngzi